# VB.NET SQL Server query to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, linq

I am trying to convert the below working query to  LINQ VB.NET, however, I am not getting the results.

```
select 
    s.id, s.LastName, COUNT(c.Id) 
from 
    Students s, Courses c
where 
    s.Id = c.Student_Id
group by 
    s.Id, s.LastName
```

I have reached so far:

```
Dim query = (From s In db.Students
                 Join c In db.Courses On s.Id Equals c.Student_Id
                 Group s, c By s.Id, s.LastName, c.Grade Into Group
                 Select New With {.Id = Id, .Name = LastName, .Counter = Group.Count
                     }).ToList
```

The results are not correct. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is apparent is the `group by` clause. On the SQL you have:

```
group by s.Id, s.LastName
```

but on Linq you also group by `c.Grade`:

```
Group s, c By s.Id, s.LastName, c.Grade Into Group
```

Another minor issue is `COUNT(c.Id)` which should count only non-null values, but you probably don't have any null values there, so it should be the same.

In many cases in Linq, if you have foreign keys and the model set up correctly, you shouldn't use `Join`. This might also work (I'm not sure this is the right syntax):

```
db.Students.Select(Function(s) New With {.Id = s.Id, .Name = s.LastName, .Counter = s.Courses.Count()}).ToList
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I have added c.Grade in LINQ by mistake